# How do I add code to thousands of html files without a header or footer?

Tags: shell, header, footer, edit, bulk

Does anyone know an easy way to go in and apply code to about 16,000 individiual static hard-coded HTML pages? Situation: my client has an ecommerce site with over 16,000 product pages, but instead of dynamically creating the pages with a data feed, they hard coded the pages. (product1.htm, product2.htm, etc. etc.)

I need to be able to go in and add a snippet of code to ALL of their pages, but they don't have a universal footer or header to add it to them easily.

Does that mean I need to go in and hand add it to every single htm page? Or do you know of a program or script that can add a snippet of code to every page like a shell script or something?

I'm not sure how to go about this, and I don't want to spend hours editing thousands of pages.

Thanks, in advance, if anyone can help.

Comment: where, in the file, do you want to add this snippet? At the top, bottom, a specific line number, ...?

Comment: If you know where to put the snippet, you certainly could do it by a shell script.

Comment: I want to add the code at the bottom of the html page, before the closing body tag. The snippet of code would either be an iframe or image code snippet.

Comment: I've never ran a shell script, so I have no idea how to execute something like this. I'm on Windows, not mac or linux/unix

Comment: @Virgil, see my update in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways you can go about solving this.

1. You could use a bash script to open all the files and
   prepend a header and append a footer. This will however change all the files.
2. You could also use Apache's `mod_rewrite` to add the header and the
   footer dynamically.

   If you take for example the page

   `/this/is/my/static/page.html`

   you could use `mod_rewrite` to change requests to:

   `modifypage.php?url=/this/is/my/static/page.html`

   This `modifypage.php` file should then take care of adding the header and footer.
3. A third solution is by using `Apache Handlers`.

   See:
   `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/handler.html`
4. Use some macro in your editor to add header and footer to all the files.
5. I bet there are more ways, but this is what I can come up with from the top of my head. Good luck!

**UPDATE** I wrongly assumed you were using Linux/Apache. I will leave this answer here, because it might be useful. However I bet there are similar solutions for your webserver! Look into 'pre processing and filtering' for your webserver.

Comment: Thanks I'll give some of these a shot.

Answer (score 1):

If your working in a linux system you could write a bash script that could go over all the files and simply append a certain amount of text infront of all the files, maybe something like this could work for you:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *.html
do

echo "add text here" >> $file

done
```

Comment: Just noticed your comment where you say you are using windows, I'm not sure what scripting language you could use in windows but in the interest of trying to help out, you could install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on your windows server and that should allow you to run bash scripts, you will have to modify the script above a bit to allow you to insert the code right after the closing body tag though, good luck!